# Подпись всех нужных файлов в InstallShield через Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, signature, installshield

Добрый день!

Использую Visual Studio 2013 Professional и InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition.
Для генерации ключей у меня донгл фирмы SafeNet. Я умею подписывать отдельные файлы вручную, через cmd.

В моем солюшен находятся 4-е проекта: unmanaged Dll, managed Dll (оболочка над первым Dll), апликация WPF и проект installshield для генерации файла установки.
На выходе проекта установки получается всего один файл (setup.exe), который содержит все нужны библиотеки и файлы для работы программы.

Вопрос: как и что надо сделать, что-бы все необходимые файлы, а так же и сам setup.exe подписывались через студию?

Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Значит я нашел часть ответа на мой вопрос.
В проекте сетапа надо открыть секцию Release (искать в solution explorer), там выбрать SingleImage.
В правой части окна появляются три таба. Вот один из них и называется Signing.
 Оставшаяся проблема - это получить pfx файл с помощью флешки SafeNet (именно этот файл нужно предоставить для подписи в InstallShield)